# ASP.NET Ajax: close window after Ajax call?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm using ASP.NET Ajax. How can I **tell the browser to close the current window** after the server call finishes (server-side code)?

I managed to do this using the ASP.NET Ajax's ScriptManager method "RegisterDataItem" in the server method (inside a button click handler):

```
sm.RegisterDataItem(ActionLabel, "action:closewindow")
```

and a hidden Label and handling it this way on the client:

```
function PageLoadingHandler(sender, args)
{
    var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
    if (dataItems['ActionLabel'] == 'action:closewindow') {
        window.close()
    }
}
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(PageLoadingHandler);
```

But it feels **dirty**. There must be a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, registering `window.close()` with `ScriptManagers` `RegisterStartupScript` method on event handler should work. For details on using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

Comment: Aargh! Yes, that worked. Many thanks! I was sure I've tried this before.