# Close a browser window of an ASP.NET and AJAX application

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

What is the best way to close a browser window of an AJAX ASP.NET application after the server-side has been executed.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250450/aspnet-ajax-close-window-after-ajax-call), but it seems a little complex for what I want to accomplish.  Or is this the best way to accomplish my task.

**UPDATE:** I have to close the window after the button is pressed

**UPDATE 1:** I tried the solution from the other SO question, and it did not work for me.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMyButton" runat="server" onClick="btnMyButton_Click" />

protected void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

---

I used the following code in my page, but the "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the windows" module window pops up.

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upApproveRequest, typeof(string), "closeWindow", "window.close();", true);
```

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @Gortok - I came up a solution to sets the OnClientClick event with the JavaScript function of the button that closes the child window when it is opened from the parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to close a browser window without the user's consent. You can log them out of their application, but you can't forcibly close the browser window.

Comment: I have to implement a different solution because of this issue.  Thank for the input.

Comment: No problem. Can I ask why you were trying to close their page?

Comment: The user would approve/deny a request in our application and they wanted to automatically close the page when they clicked the approve or deny button.

Comment: @hyprsleepy Actually, it is. If you do `window.top.close()`, it will tell the user that the window wants to close, but they still have to ok it. That's why my answer is accurate, you still need the user's consent to actually close the window.

Comment: @George - No, if you use the code I have in my answer it will close without asking.  I have it doing that right now in my website.  Try and make a command button with my code in the click event and see what happens when you click on it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do this by placing the following code in your button click event.

```
protected void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Update database
    bool success = Presenter.DoDatabaseStuff();

    if (success)
    {
        // Close window after success
        const string javaScript = "<script language=javascript>window.top.close();</script>";
        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("CloseMyWindow"))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"CloseMyWindow", javaScript);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Display failure result
        result_msg_area.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "An error occurred!";                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the script warning, you can use this:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');window.close();
```

So:

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upApproveRequest, typeof(string), "closeWindow", "window.open('', '_self', '');window.close();", true);
```

Answer (score -2):

That's pretty much it. You can just use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...)`